# Function is not returning correct output

Tags: python, function, loops

```
def transpose(matrix):
    n=0
    finalList = []
    while n < (len(matrix)):
        li = []
        for sets in matrix:
            li.append(sets[n])
        finalList.append(li)
        n += 1
    return finalList
```

I am trying to transpose([[1,2]]) and return [[1],[2]] as the result but am only getting [[1]] in return. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you debug it and see? Going through the execution with a debugger or even with pen and paper could easily tell you why.

Comment: Well the problem is that it works when doing transpose([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]) or transpose([[1]]). Was wondering if it was an easy fix or if it needs to be restructured.

Comment: Well if it doesn't completely work, probably yes. But first, *figure out what's wrong*.

Comment: Put some print statements/functions in to see what is going on - though pen and paper works too.

Comment: I don't quite understand using a `while` loop over a `for` loop. But I would suggest looking at what `len(matrix)` returns for `[[1, 2]]` and then see if `n` reaches what you would expect.

Comment: I don't get the down votes or the close votes: he has presented his attempt, he shows a call with an input along with the actual output and the expected output. This is a far cry better than many questions posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For easy fix, change only `len(matrix)` part to `len(matrix[0])`

```
def transpose(matrix):
        n=0
        finalList = []
        while n < (len(matrix[0])):
            li = []
            for sets in matrix:
                li.append(sets[n])
            finalList.append(li)
            n += 1
        return finalList
```